# Need to Run VBA code in Command Prompt

Tags: vba, batch-file, tiff

I have a Tiff file splitter DLL that has a VBA code:

```
Dim tsplit As New SCTiffPageSplitNetDLL.TiffPageSplitterDLL
Dim rslt as Integer
To call the function and split TIFF files, you could use the following:

rslt = tsplit.Tiff_PageSplit("C:\test\test.tif", "C:\outputdir") 
MsgBox rslt
```

How can I run this line of code in a `command prompt`? I need to make a batch file(.bat) out of this code.

Answer (score 1):

You could put it in a VBScript (.vbs) file and run it using cscript. See this thread [How to run a .vbs from a .bat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216285/how-to-run-a-vbs-from-a-bat)

Comment: How would you put it into a vbs? Thank you.

Comment: I have tried this but no luck:

Set Obj = CreateObject("TiffPageSplitDLL.TiffPageSplitterDLL")

strPath = "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\"
strFile = "splitme.tif"
strDest = "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\"

strFile = strPath & strFile

rslt = obj.Tiff_PageSplit(cstr(strFile), strDest) 

Set Obj = Nothing

Comment: Yes, I got: ActiveX component can’t create object: ‘TiffPageSplitDLL.TiffPageSplitterDLL’. Is it a code error or it can’t really be created?

Comment: This means that the DLL is not registered, or you got its name wrong. I notice that you have called it SCTiffPageSplitNetDLL.TiffPageSplitterDLL in your VBA code, but TiffPageSplitDLL.TiffPageSplitterDLL in your VBScript code... this could be the problem.

Comment: I get the same error on both names. The DLL has been registered successfully. Thanks for your replies btw.

Comment: Hmm... I still think it must be an issue with the name you're passing. Try using this utility http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/registered_dll_view.html to be absolutely sure.

Comment: If you can create it in VBA without issue, then you should be able to create it in VBScript also.

Comment: Does the existing VBA code actually work? You need to confirm that works first before assuming there is an issue with VBS. Note that your posted VBA code is actually non-functional as you're missing a comment mark