# Logging onto a site using a .batch file

Tags: batch-file, authentication

So I'm wondering if there is a way to log onto a site automatically using a batch file, so i can just click on the file and it will open the browser, site and just log me on, without having to manually log on. For example if i wanted to automatically log on to my [Bing.com](http://bing.com/) account, i could just click on the batch file and it would open the browser and log me on. I have no clue where to start on trying to figure this out so i could really use some help.

Comment: yes , but without external tools you can do this only with internet explorer

Comment: Batch doesn't play nice with GUIs. Doing things to web pages is more of a job for Javascript.

Comment: Maybe you could [re-purpose one of these scripts](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35594057/1683264) to suit your evil plans?

Answer (score 1):

There could be an indirect way in Google Chrome:

1. Find the login page of the website where you put your login and password.
2. Try to get the id or html tag of the login and password elements of the page.
3. Create a chrome extension file or simply a *sample.user.js* file to run some Javascript commands on the page.
4. Here is a sample to put your credentials in the fields of the page:

   ```
   document.getElementById('login').value="*[login]*"   
   document.getElementById('password').value="*[password]*"
   document.getElementsByTagName('input')[3].click()
   ```
5. In the manifest of extension file or in the `@include` of *user.js* file, define the login page of website to let the extension work just in that page.
6. Install the extension, here is a help [how to install chrome extension manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258989/manually-adding-a-userscript-to-google-chrome)
7. Now you can run chrome from terminal or .batch file to open the login page in chrome browser. take a look at [how to open chrome from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348840/opening-chrome-from-command-line)
8. Done!

Answer (score 0):

There is a way that works in IE :

1. write a .vbs script to login to your website, like this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24038230/fill-user-name-and-password-in-a-webpage-using-vba)
2. execute your vbs script from command line or .bat file, look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216285/how-to-run-a-vbs-from-a-bat)